# Possible reasons for threads getting stuck in getDeclaredConstructors?

Tags: java, multithreading, reflection

For one installation of our application we have been seeing issues on production that were reported as "system is getting slower" or "requests never returning" by the users. In the end the server had to be restarted. We had several of those incidents and a nightly restart of the server seems to be working as a workaround.

Our application makes heavy use of dynamic classloading (.jar files stored in database as blobs) and reflection.
Environment details:

- Java 1.7.021
- OS: Linux (2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64)
- JBoss EAP 6.2
- Appdynamics is beeing used
- memory and gc settings: -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=2560m -Xms2048m -Xmx10240m -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC

We switched to

- Java 1.7.080
- -XX:+UseG1GC

but it looks like we are still facing the issue.

What we are seeing in the logfiles, heapdumps, threadumps and gc logs so fare is the following

- We are not seeing any OutOfMemory errors
- Memory consumption of both Heap and PermGend seems to be ok (heap and perm gen not fully used)
- With Java 1.7.021 and parallelGC we saw a couple of long running (5 minutes) Full GCs - this does not seem to happen anymore after switching to G1GC (which is what we expected)
- we don't see any warnings related to the CodeCache beeing full in the logs

What we are seeing is

- for some of the incidents the number of DelegatingClassLoaders in the heapdump was around 5000 for others it was around 100 000.
- that after initial reports from users that the system is getting slow the number of threads that are in state RUNNABLE and are working on "getDeclaredConstructors0" is increasing (from just two in the beginning to around 50. The thread seems to "hang" at the same position (well they are in state RUNNABLE) for multiple hours.

See below for an excerpt of the threadump:

```
"http-xxx:8443-141" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007efe9412f000 nid=0x64fb runnable [0x00007efe1ba8a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateMethod(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    [application code]

"http-xxx:8443-138" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007efe9412a000 nid=0x64ed runnable [0x00007efe1c397000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateMethod(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.mvel2.PropertyAccessor.set(PropertyAccessor.java:350)
    at org.mvel2.PropertyAccessor.set(PropertyAccessor.java:134)
    at org.mvel2.MVEL.setProperty(MVEL.java:1088)   
    [application code]
```

The situation after updating to Java 1.7.80 / G1Gc seems to be similar. Unfortunately no threadump available, just wicket warnings in the log)

```
2016-03-10 15:00:39,009 WARN  [http-xxx:7443-23] org.apache.wicket.page.PageAccessSynchronizer: Thread 'http-xxx:7443-23' failed to acquire lock to page with id '28', attempted for 3 minutes out of allowed 3 minutes. The thread that holds the lock has name 'http-xxx:7443-18'.
2016-03-10 15:00:39,017 WARN  [http-xxx:7443-23] org.apache.wicket.page.PageAccessSynchronizer: "http-xxx:7443-18" daemon prio=5 tid=8950 state=RUNNABLE 
org.apache.wicket.util.lang.Threads$ThreadDump
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:331)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1133)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    [application code]

2016-03-10 15:04:14,640 WARN  [http-xxx:7443-16] org.apache.wicket.page.PageAccessSynchronizer: Thread 'http-xxx:7443-16' failed to acquire lock to page with id '11', attempted for 3 minutes out of allowed 3 minutes. The thread that holds the lock has name 'http-xxx:7443-38'.
2016-03-10 15:04:14,642 WARN  [http-xxx:7443-16] org.apache.wicket.page.PageAccessSynchronizer: "http-xxx:7443-38" daemon prio=5 tid=9088 state=RUNNABLE 
org.apache.wicket.util.lang.Threads$ThreadDump
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateMethod(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
    [application code]
```

We are currently unable to reproduce this (still working on that). But maybe somebody in the community has seen something similar and has an idea what could help us to reproduce or solve the issues. 
One guess that we currently having is that this is related to native memory consumption (Because of information like http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-nativememory-linux/) but we don't see any hints in this regards in the logs (no OutOfMemory errors, no reports from the linux administrators that the system is running out of memory)

Comment: Java Serialization is not very efficient and it called reflection a lot. If you call it enough it will be a bottle neck. It could be that this method is single threaded so that when one thread is using it all the others have to wait.

Comment: It is pretty amazing it is building a Constructor for each class even if it is only writing the class (on every ObjectOutputStream)  If you have a lot of classes, in each Stream it will take much longer.

Comment: I would definitely first remove Appdynamics from the equation; instrumenting bytecode can certainly cause problems.

Comment: You are right. I guess this is what the client ultimately did. I've added an answere and marked it as solved for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We never were able to properly solve the issue but at some point it vanished. If I'm not wrong one the client change the appdynamics configuration / removed it which seemed to have solved the issue.